# Countdown timer in service class

Tags: android, android-service

Currently I am creating a Service for countdown timer and I want to run the timer even if the application is destroyed.

If I use  `START_NOT_STICKY` than it stops the service on Application destroy. and If I use `START_STICKY` than its restart the service on Application destroy.

Here is my code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements   View.OnClickListener{
Button btn_testing;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    init();
    listener();

}

private void init(){
    btn_testing = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_testing);


}

private void listener(){
    btn_testing.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()){


        case R.id.btn_testing:
            startService(new Intent(this, Service_Tesing.class));
            break;
    }

}
```

}

Here is my Service class:

```
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.util.Log;



public class Service_Tesing extends Service {


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(30000,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.e("Timer", millisUntilFinished+"");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.e("Finish","Finish");

        }
    }.start();


}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    stopSelf();
    return START_STICKY;

//        return Service.START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: `I want to run the timer even if the application is destory` then run it in separate process

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem I had use the TimerTask in service. Here you can find the demo of [Android Countdown Timer Run In Background](https://deepshikhapuri.wordpress.com/2016/11/07/android-countdown-timer-run-in-background/)

Thanks